# Issue with subscriber callback as publihser

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the code prototype shown  [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/59725/publishing-to-a-topic-via-subscriber-callback-function/?answer=59738#post-id-59738)

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

class SubscribeAndPublish
{
public:
    SubscribeAndPublish()
    {
        pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int16>("same_topic",1);
        sub = nh.subscribe<std_msgs::Int16>("same_topic",1,&SubscribeAndPublish::callback,this);
    }
    void callback(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& msg) 
    {
        ROS_INFO("I heard this data: [%d]", msg->data);
        std_msgs::Int16 msg_p;
        msg_p.data = msg->data;
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(" I got some data");
        pub.publish(msg_p);
    }
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        ros::Publisher pub;
        ros::Subscriber sub;

};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc,argv,"node");
    SubscribeAndPublish ps;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

When I  executes the code, it is waiting (for input) and I gave some integers as follows

```
12
123324
 43534
23452345
342
153
5234
```

The program is not printing anything and still waits for input, but when I kill the node, (only) numbers are printing on command lines.

Why the program is not working as expected? where I went wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285327/issue-with-subscriber-callback-as-publihser/) by [hagm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33308/hagm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your callback is publishing on the same topic it is listening on, so the first time it receives anything it will publish and trigger it self forever:

```
[[/node] :[17] [ I got some data]
[[/node] :[14] [I heard this data: [0]]
[[/node] :[17] [ I got some data]
[[/node] :[14] [I heard this data: [0]]
[[/node] :[17] [ I got 
...
```

It prints out fine on my system, but maybe yours can't keep up with it?

```
rostopic hz /same_topic
subscribed to [/same_topic]
average rate: 18782.57
```

(!)

The queue size is just one so only randomly can a competing publisher inject a message into the infinite loop, it has to beat the self published message into the queue.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2